# SwiftUI - detecting speed without location

Tags: swift

So I understand that speed seems to be linked to the CoreLocation system in Swift

Am wondering if a user does not allow their location to be tracked, is there anyway to track if a user is going above X speed.

Our state Western Australia has brought in a law that makes it illegal to access any app that uses internet while driving.

So to assist with this we need to add a driving detection script, and show a driving screen when above X speed.

Note I can do this with Location services. But we are unable to force a user to allow location (I guess we could force location on).

Comment: Without external services (Location in this case) our phone is just a metal-glass brick... can you detect your speed having a brick in hands? And, btw, SwiftUI has nothing to speed/location detection at all.

Comment: @Asperi I totally get that, I was just asking because we have noticed that people don’t really want to give us their location, unfortunately this law makes not only the user legally liable but also the app developer, so we have to either force location services or figure another way.

Comment: Yeees... laws... ))

Comment: @Asperi yep, totally hate it to. But it’s a 1500$ fine + 4 demerit points for the driver and up to $5000 for the app developer aka the company who released the app. (Only if the app developer is from Western Australia) - which guess what I am :(